# Is it safe to comment out kwallet in lightdm and lightdm-greeter?

Tags: pam, kwallet, pam-environment

I have a problem. I am getting some annoying logs of pam_kwallet not found. This is because of kwallet is not installed in my system.

If I run the command more /etc/pam.d/* I am getting the below output: -

I found that in lightdm and lightdm-greeter. It is getting loaded.

If I comment those lines, will it be safe?

## (Replaces the use of /etc/limits in old login)

session    required   pam_limits.so

## The standard Unix authentication modules, used with

## NIS (man nsswitch) as well as normal /etc/passwd and

## /etc/shadow entries.

@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-session

## %PAM-1.0

session    required   pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=0
session    required   pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale user_readenv=0
@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-session-noninteractive

## This file is part of systemd.

#

## Used by systemd --user instances.

@include common-account

session  required pam_selinux.so close
session  required pam_selinux.so nottys open
@include common-session-noninteractive
session optional pam_systemd.so
@include common-auth
auth optional pam_gnome_keyring.so

## %PAM-1.0

@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-session
@include common-password
#

## /etc/pam.d/xscreensaver - PAM behavior for xscreensaver

#

@include common-auth
@include common-account
aravind@comp:/etc/pam.d$ clear

aravind@comp:/etc/pam.d$ more *
::::::::::::::
chfn
::::::::::::::
#

## The PAM configuration file for the Shadow `chfn' service

#

## This allows root to change user infomation without being

## prompted for a password

auth        sufficient  pam_rootok.so

## The standard Unix authentication modules, used with

## NIS (man nsswitch) as well as normal /etc/passwd and

## /etc/shadow entries.

@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-session

::::::::::::::
chpasswd
::::::::::::::

## The PAM configuration file for the Shadow 'chpasswd' service

#

@include common-password

::::::::::::::
chsh
::::::::::::::
#

## The PAM configuration file for the Shadow `chsh' service

#

## This will not allow a user to change their shell unless

## their current one is listed in /etc/shells. This keeps

## accounts with special shells from changing them.

auth       required   pam_shells.so

## This allows root to change user shell without being

## prompted for a password

auth        sufficient  pam_rootok.so

## The standard Unix authentication modules, used with

## NIS (man nsswitch) as well as normal /etc/passwd and

## /etc/shadow entries.

@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-session

::::::::::::::
common-account
::::::::::::::
#

## /etc/pam.d/common-account - authorization settings common to all services

#

## This file is included from other service-specific PAM config files,

## and should contain a list of the authorization modules that define

## the central access policy for use on the system.  The default is to

## only deny service to users whose accounts are expired in /etc/shadow.

#

## As of pam 1.0.1-6, this file is managed by pam-auth-update by default.

## To take advantage of this, it is recommended that you configure any

## local modules either before or after the default block, and use

## pam-auth-update to manage selection of other modules.  See

## pam-auth-update(8) for details.

#

## here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)

account [success=1 new_authtok_reqd=done default=ignore]    pam_unix.so

## here's the fallback if no module succeeds

account requisite           pam_deny.so

## prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;

## this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code

## since the modules above will each just jump around

account required            pam_permit.so

## and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)

## end of pam-auth-update config

::::::::::::::
common-auth
::::::::::::::
#

## /etc/pam.d/common-auth - authentication settings common to all services

#

## This file is included from other service-specific PAM config files,

## and should contain a list of the authentication modules that define

## the central authentication scheme for use on the system

## (e.g., /etc/shadow, LDAP, Kerberos, etc.).  The default is to use the

## traditional Unix authentication mechanisms.

#

## As of pam 1.0.1-6, this file is managed by pam-auth-update by default.

## To take advantage of this, it is recommended that you configure any

## local modules either before or after the default block, and use

## pam-auth-update to manage selection of other modules.  See

## pam-auth-update(8) for details.

## here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)

auth    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so nullok_secure

## here's the fallback if no module succeeds

auth    requisite           pam_deny.so

## prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;

## this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code

## since the modules above will each just jump around

auth    required            pam_permit.so

## and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)

auth    optional    pam_ecryptfs.so unwrap

## end of pam-auth-update config

::::::::::::::
common-password
::::::::::::::
#

## /etc/pam.d/common-password - password-related modules common to all services

#

## This file is included from other service-specific PAM config files,

## and should contain a list of modules that define the services to be

## used to change user passwords.  The default is pam_unix.

## Explanation of pam_unix options:

#

## The "sha512" option enables salted SHA512 passwords.  Without this option,

## the default is Unix crypt.  Prior releases used the option "md5".

#

## The "obscure" option replaces the old `OBSCURE_CHECKS_ENAB' option in

## login.defs.

#

## See the pam_unix manpage for other options.

## As of pam 1.0.1-6, this file is managed by pam-auth-update by default.

## To take advantage of this, it is recommended that you configure any

## local modules either before or after the default block, and use

## pam-auth-update to manage selection of other modules.  See

## pam-auth-update(8) for details.

## here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)

password    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so obscure sha512

## here's the fallback if no module succeeds

password    requisite           pam_deny.so

## prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;

## this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code

## since the modules above will each just jump around

password    required            pam_permit.so

## and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)

password    optional    pam_gnome_keyring.so 
password    optional    pam_ecryptfs.so

## end of pam-auth-update config

::::::::::::::
common-session
::::::::::::::
#

## /etc/pam.d/common-session - session-related modules common to all services

#

## This file is included from other service-specific PAM config files,

## and should contain a list of modules that define tasks to be performed

## at the start and end of sessions of *any* kind (both interactive and

## non-interactive).

#

## As of pam 1.0.1-6, this file is managed by pam-auth-update by default.

## To take advantage of this, it is recommended that you configure any

## local modules either before or after the default block, and use

## pam-auth-update to manage selection of other modules.  See

## pam-auth-update(8) for details.

## here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)

session [default=1]         pam_permit.so

## here's the fallback if no module succeeds

session requisite           pam_deny.so

## prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;

## this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code

## since the modules above will each just jump around

session required            pam_permit.so

## The pam_umask module will set the umask according to the system default in

## /etc/login.defs and user settings, solving the problem of different

## umask settings with different shells, display managers, remote sessions etc.

## See "man pam_umask".

session optional            pam_umask.so

## and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)

session required    pam_unix.so 
session optional    pam_systemd.so 
session optional    pam_ecryptfs.so unwrap

## end of pam-auth-update config

::::::::::::::
common-session-noninteractive
::::::::::::::
#

## /etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive - session-related modules

## common to all non-interactive services

#

## This file is included from other service-specific PAM config files,

## and should contain a list of modules that define tasks to be performed

## at the start and end of all non-interactive sessions.

#

## As of pam 1.0.1-6, this file is managed by pam-auth-update by default.

## To take advantage of this, it is recommended that you configure any

## local modules either before or after the default block, and use

## pam-auth-update to manage selection of other modules.  See

## pam-auth-update(8) for details.

## here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)

session [default=1]         pam_permit.so

## here's the fallback if no module succeeds

session requisite           pam_deny.so

## prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;

## this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code

## since the modules above will each just jump around

session required            pam_permit.so

## The pam_umask module will set the umask according to the system default in

## /etc/login.defs and user settings, solving the problem of different

## umask settings with different shells, display managers, remote sessions etc.

## See "man pam_umask".

session optional            pam_umask.so

## and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)

session required    pam_unix.so 
session optional    pam_ecryptfs.so unwrap

## end of pam-auth-update config

::::::::::::::
cron
::::::::::::::

## The PAM configuration file for the cron daemon

@include common-auth

## Sets the loginuid process attribute

session    required     pam_loginuid.so

## Read environment variables from pam_env's default files, /etc/environment

## and /etc/security/pam_env.conf.

session       required   pam_env.so

## In addition, read system locale information

session       required   pam_env.so envfile=/etc/default/locale

@include common-account
@include common-session-noninteractive

## Sets up user limits, please define limits for cron tasks

## through /etc/security/limits.conf

session    required   pam_limits.so

::::::::::::::
cups
::::::::::::::
@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-session
::::::::::::::
gdm-autologin
::::::::::::::

## %PAM-1.0

auth    requisite       pam_nologin.so
auth    required    pam_succeed_if.so user != root quiet_success
auth    required        pam_permit.so
@include common-account

## SELinux needs to be the first session rule. This ensures that any

## lingering context has been cleared. Without this it is possible

## that a module could execute code in the wrong domain.

session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad]        pam_selinux.so close
session required        pam_loginuid.so

## SELinux needs to intervene at login time to ensure that the process

## starts in the proper default security context. Only sessions which are

## intended to run in the user's context should be run after this.

session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad]        pam_selinux.so open
session optional        pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session required        pam_limits.so
session required        pam_env.so readenv=1
session required        pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale
@include common-session
@include common-password
::::::::::::::
gdm-launch-environment
::::::::::::::

## %PAM-1.0

auth    requisite       pam_nologin.so
auth    required        pam_permit.so
@include common-account
session optional        pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session required        pam_limits.so
session required        pam_env.so readenv=1
session required        pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale
@include common-session
@include common-password
::::::::::::::
gdm-password
::::::::::::::

## %PAM-1.0

auth    requisite       pam_nologin.so
auth    required    pam_succeed_if.so user != root quiet_success
@include common-auth
auth    optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so
@include common-account

## SELinux needs to be the first session rule. This ensures that any

## lingering context has been cleared. Without this it is possible

## that a module could execute code in the wrong domain.

session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad]        pam_selinux.so close
session required        pam_loginuid.so

## SELinux needs to intervene at login time to ensure that the process

## starts in the proper default security context. Only sessions which are

## intended to run in the user's context should be run after this.

session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad]        pam_selinux.so open
session optional        pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session required        pam_limits.so
session required        pam_env.so readenv=1
session required        pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale
@include common-session
session optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so auto_start
@include common-password
::::::::::::::
gnome-screensaver
::::::::::::::
@include common-auth
auth optional pam_gnome_keyring.so
::::::::::::::
lightdm
::::::::::::::

## %PAM-1.0

auth    requisite       pam_nologin.so
auth    sufficient      pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup nopasswdlogin
@include common-auth
auth    optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so
auth    optional        pam_kwallet.so
auth    optional        pam_kwallet5.so
@include common-account
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad] pam_selinux.so close

## session required        pam_loginuid.so

session required        pam_limits.so
@include common-session
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad] pam_selinux.so open
session optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so auto_start
session optional        pam_kwallet.so auto_start
session optional        pam_kwallet5.so auto_start
session required        pam_env.so readenv=1
session required        pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale
@include common-password
::::::::::::::
lightdm-autologin
::::::::::::::

## %PAM-1.0

auth    requisite       pam_nologin.so
auth    required        pam_permit.so
@include common-account
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad] pam_selinux.so close

## session required        pam_loginuid.so

session required        pam_limits.so
@include common-session
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad] pam_selinux.so open
session required        pam_env.so readenv=1
session required        pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale
@include common-password
::::::::::::::
lightdm-greeter
::::::::::::::

## %PAM-1.0

auth    required        pam_permit.so
auth    optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so
auth    optional        pam_kwallet.so
auth    optional        pam_kwallet5.so
@include common-account
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad] pam_selinux.so close
session required        pam_limits.so
@include common-session
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad] pam_selinux.so open
session optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so auto_start
session optional        pam_kwallet.so auto_start
session optional        pam_kwallet5.so auto_start
session required        pam_env.so readenv=1
session required        pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale
::::::::::::::
login
::::::::::::::
#

## The PAM configuration file for the Shadow `login' service

#

## Enforce a minimal delay in case of failure (in microseconds).

## (Replaces the `FAIL_DELAY' setting from login.defs)

## Note that other modules may require another minimal delay. (for example,

## to disable any delay, you should add the nodelay option to pam_unix)

auth       optional   pam_faildelay.so  delay=3000000

## Outputs an issue file prior to each login prompt (Replaces the

## ISSUE_FILE option from login.defs). Uncomment for use

## auth       required   pam_issue.so issue=/etc/issue

## Disallows root logins except on tty's listed in /etc/securetty

## (Replaces the `CONSOLE' setting from login.defs)

#

## With the default control of this module:

## [success=ok new_authtok_reqd=ok ignore=ignore user_unknown=bad default=die]

## root will not be prompted for a password on insecure lines.

## if an invalid username is entered, a password is prompted (but login

## will eventually be rejected)

#

## You can change it to a "requisite" module if you think root may mis-type

## her login and should not be prompted for a password in that case. But

## this will leave the system as vulnerable to user enumeration attacks.

#

## You can change it to a "required" module if you think it permits to

## guess valid user names of your system (invalid user names are considered

## as possibly being root on insecure lines), but root passwords may be

## communicated over insecure lines.

auth [success=ok new_authtok_reqd=ok ignore=ignore user_unknown=bad default=die] pam_securetty.so

## Disallows other than root logins when /etc/nologin exists

## (Replaces the `NOLOGINS_FILE' option from login.defs)

auth       requisite  pam_nologin.so

## SELinux needs to be the first session rule. This ensures that any

## lingering context has been cleared. Without out this it is possible

## that a module could execute code in the wrong domain.

## When the module is present, "required" would be sufficient (When SELinux

## is disabled, this returns success.)

session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad] pam_selinux.so close

## This module parses environment configuration file(s)

## and also allows you to use an extended config

## file /etc/security/pam_env.conf.

## parsing /etc/environment needs "readenv=1"

session       required   pam_env.so readenv=1

## locale variables are also kept into /etc/default/locale in etch

## reading this file *in addition to /etc/environment* does not hurt

session       required   pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale

## Standard Un*x authentication.

@include common-auth

## This allows certain extra groups to be granted to a user

## based on things like time of day, tty, service, and user.

## Please edit /etc/security/group.conf to fit your needs

## (Replaces the `CONSOLE_GROUPS' option in login.defs)

auth       optional   pam_group.so

## Uncomment and edit /etc/security/time.conf if you need to set

## time restrainst on logins.

## (Replaces the `PORTTIME_CHECKS_ENAB' option from login.defs

## as well as /etc/porttime)

## account    requisite  pam_time.so

## Uncomment and edit /etc/security/access.conf if you need to

## set access limits.

## (Replaces /etc/login.access file)

## account  required       pam_access.so

## Sets up user limits according to /etc/security/limits.conf

## (Replaces the use of /etc/limits in old login)

session    required   pam_limits.so

## Prints the last login info upon succesful login

## (Replaces the `LASTLOG_ENAB' option from login.defs)

session    optional   pam_lastlog.so

## Prints the message of the day upon succesful login.

## (Replaces the `MOTD_FILE' option in login.defs)

## This includes a dynamically generated part from /run/motd.dynamic

## and a static (admin-editable) part from /etc/motd.

session    optional   pam_motd.so motd=/run/motd.dynamic
session    optional   pam_motd.so noupdate

## Prints the status of the user's mailbox upon succesful login

## (Replaces the `MAIL_CHECK_ENAB' option from login.defs).

#

## This also defines the MAIL environment variable

## However, userdel also needs MAIL_DIR and MAIL_FILE variables

## in /etc/login.defs to make sure that removing a user

## also removes the user's mail spool file.

## See comments in /etc/login.defs

session    optional   pam_mail.so standard

## Sets the loginuid process attribute

session    required     pam_loginuid.so

## Standard Un*x account and session

@include common-account
@include common-session
@include common-password

## SELinux needs to intervene at login time to ensure that the process

## starts in the proper default security context. Only sessions which are

## intended to run in the user's context should be run after this.

session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad] pam_selinux.so open

## When the module is present, "required" would be sufficient (When SELinux

## is disabled, this returns success.)

::::::::::::::
newusers
::::::::::::::

## The PAM configuration file for the Shadow 'newusers' service

#

@include common-password

::::::::::::::
other
::::::::::::::
#

## /etc/pam.d/other - specify the PAM fallback behaviour

#

## Note that this file is used for any unspecified service; for example

## if /etc/pam.d/cron  specifies no session modules but cron calls

## pam_open_session, the session module out of /etc/pam.d/other is

## used.  If you really want nothing to happen then use pam_permit.so or

## pam_deny.so as appropriate.

## We fall back to the system default in /etc/pam.d/common-*

@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-password
@include common-session
::::::::::::::
passwd
::::::::::::::
#

## The PAM configuration file for the Shadow `passwd' service

#

@include common-password

::::::::::::::
polkit-1
::::::::::::::

## %PAM-1.0

@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-password
session       required   pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=0
session       required   pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale user_readenv=0
@include common-session
::::::::::::::
ppp
::::::::::::::

## %PAM-1.0

## Information for the PPPD process with the 'login' option.

auth    required    pam_nologin.so
@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-session
::::::::::::::
runuser
::::::::::::::

## %PAM-1.0

auth        sufficient  pam_rootok.so
session     optional    pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required    pam_limits.so
session     required    pam_unix.so
::::::::::::::
runuser-l
::::::::::::::

## %PAM-1.0

auth        include     runuser
session     optional    pam_keyinit.so force revoke
-session    optional    pam_systemd.so
session     include     runuser
::::::::::::::
samba
::::::::::::::
@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-session-noninteractive
::::::::::::::
sesman
::::::::::::::

## %PAM-1.0

@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-session
@include common-password
::::::::::::::
su
::::::::::::::
#

## The PAM configuration file for the Shadow `su' service

#

## This allows root to su without passwords (normal operation)

auth       sufficient pam_rootok.so

## Uncomment this to force users to be a member of group root

## before they can use `su'. You can also add "group=foo"

## to the end of this line if you want to use a group other

## than the default "root" (but this may have side effect of

## denying "root" user, unless she's a member of "foo" or explicitly

## permitted earlier by e.g. "sufficient pam_rootok.so").

## (Replaces the `SU_WHEEL_ONLY' option from login.defs)

## auth       required   pam_wheel.so

## Uncomment this if you want wheel members to be able to

## su without a password.

## auth       sufficient pam_wheel.so trust

## Uncomment this if you want members of a specific group to not

## be allowed to use su at all.

## auth       required   pam_wheel.so deny group=nosu

## Uncomment and edit /etc/security/time.conf if you need to set

## time restrainst on su usage.

## (Replaces the `PORTTIME_CHECKS_ENAB' option from login.defs

## as well as /etc/porttime)

## account    requisite  pam_time.so

## This module parses environment configuration file(s)

## and also allows you to use an extended config

## file /etc/security/pam_env.conf.

## parsing /etc/environment needs "readenv=1"

session       required   pam_env.so readenv=1

## locale variables are also kept into /etc/default/locale in etch

## reading this file *in addition to /etc/environment* does not hurt

session       required   pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale

## Defines the MAIL environment variable

## However, userdel also needs MAIL_DIR and MAIL_FILE variables

## in /etc/login.defs to make sure that removing a user

## also removes the user's mail spool file.

## See comments in /etc/login.defs

#

## "nopen" stands to avoid reporting new mail when su'ing to another user

session    optional   pam_mail.so nopen

## Sets up user limits according to /etc/security/limits.conf

## (Replaces the use of /etc/limits in old login)

session    required   pam_limits.so

## The standard Unix authentication modules, used with

## NIS (man nsswitch) as well as normal /etc/passwd and

## /etc/shadow entries.

@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-session

::::::::::::::
sudo
::::::::::::::

## %PAM-1.0

session    required   pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=0
session    required   pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale user_readenv=0
@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-session-noninteractive
::::::::::::::
systemd-user
::::::::::::::

## This file is part of systemd.

#

## Used by systemd --user instances.

@include common-account

session  required pam_selinux.so close
session  required pam_selinux.so nottys open
@include common-session-noninteractive
session optional pam_systemd.so
::::::::::::::
unity
::::::::::::::
@include common-auth
auth optional pam_gnome_keyring.so
::::::::::::::
xrdp-sesman
::::::::::::::

## %PAM-1.0

@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-session
@include common-password
::::::::::::::
xscreensaver
::::::::::::::
#

## /etc/pam.d/xscreensaver - PAM behavior for xscreensaver

#

@include common-auth
@include common-account
aravind@comp:/etc/pam.d$

Comment: kwallet is a KDE (Kubuntu) app. Did you switch from KDE desktop or delete kwallet?

Comment: Yes, I have tried KDE, removed the enviroment and switched back .

Comment: try reconfiguring LightDM and LightDM-greeter

Comment: @ravery Do you want to say sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm

Comment: @Aravid -- yes, that is the command. and also for the greeter.

Comment: I am getting the message dpkg-query: package 'lightdm-greeter' is not installed and no information is available
I am using Ubuntu 16.04, should I install lightdm-greeter

Comment: the package is probably lightdm-gtk-greeter

Comment: I have sudo dpkg-reconfigure unity-greeter

Comment: dpkg-query: package 'lightdm-gtk-greeter' is not installed and no information is available

Comment: you already said you have unity-greeter .... not lightdm greeter

Comment: But is it safe to comment out the PAM config files. the programs are not installed . These optional sessions making delay of login. sometime it is becomming non responsive.

Comment: @ravery , Sir I have commented the lines. No error. But I think it is not the problem that I am looking for.  Thanks for your help